# Normalize a schema when data required depends on "status field"?

Tags: database-design

I have a `User` database table that has the following fields,

```
Id
Username
Password
Status_id
```

A status table consists of just an `Id` and `title` field, that has values of `Pending`, `On Hold`, `Active` and `Completed`.

When the status is changed to `Pending`, I want to record in a separate table the id of the admin who changed the user to this status, `date_changed(datetime)` and the `reason(text)` for them being pending.

When `On Hold`, I want to know the `reason(text)` why, the date / time they went on hold and the time they will become off hold.

For `Completed` I'd like to know the `final_grade(int)` they got, any `comments(text)` and filename of an attached file.

This causes me a headache due to the many status types and i'm wondering what database design is best to suit for this?

I'm using a PHP Form to change the status value if anyone is wondering, then i'd input the values appropriate dependant on the chosen value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used [Doctrine Inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) which solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just make a new Table for each Status type and put in a record each time the status changed? That way, each status has it's own fields.

Some joins should allow you to find whatever information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logs table as:

```
tbl_logs | id | moderator | user | from_status | to_status | timestamp | reason
```

- moderator and user are foreign key to user table.
- from_status, to_status are foreign key to status table
- reason is text

*Note* :

- `from_status` is redundant, you can get its value from previous `to_status` by sorting logs over timestamp.
- I am not sure about `final_grade`. If its only for logistics purpose you can put it in logs, if its intrinsic to User, you can keep it in User table.